# Is there any state-by-state data on approval for LBJ or the Vietnam War?

Tags: data-request, usa, politics, state

I cannot find any data on approval ratings for LBJ on a state by state level.

(Recommendations for sources of political/cultural data in general, especially of the sort that can't be readily found on google, would be appreciated.)